# Error not displaying in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

Why can't I see what the Error is. On youtube, when they forgot to put in a ; an error along with which file and which line on that file was displayed. When I get an error, I just get:

> Server Error
>
> 500 - Internal server error.  There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

How do I get it to show what the error is?

Comment: How php is installed?

Comment: Look at your server logs.

Comment: @RUJordan Yes. That is all that is displayed and I get it no matter what the error is.

Comment: @zerkms PHP is on godaddy host.

Comment: @MikeBrant How do you do that?

Comment: @Makai Go to GoDaddy's website. Log in. Find the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a server error, and not a php error, but in your php.ini file towards the bottom and not in the examples, there are error reporting options. Be sure you change them back to no, after the error is corrected, this is a security measure to keep your code private.

As far as a 500 error, check your apache logs.

Comment: I do not have PHP downloaded. I am just using the PHP on godaddy host.

Comment: "I think that is a server error, and not a php error" --- this is a terribly wrong assumption.

Comment: not when it says server error at the top of the post and internal server error within.  Makai, you may have access to your php.ini file through the c-panel.